# ServiceFabric StatefulService method passed Actor Proxy DataContract error

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a `StatefulService` with a method. The first argument of the method accepts an interface type that corresponds to one of my Actors. The Actor calls the service method using `ServiceProxy`, passing `this` in as the first argument. This compiles file. The signatures match.

When running however, I get an error about an unexpected type of IMyActorType not being known to the `DataContractSerializer`. I know what this message means. Does `ServiceProxy` not handle `ActorReferences`? I know `ActorProxy` works. I can pass one Actor to another Actor using `ActorProxy`.

Or is this maybe some problem in my configuration of the `StatefulService`? Something with my `ServiceReplicaListener` setup?

I have worked around this issue for now by changing the method signatures of my `StatefulService` methods to `ActorReference`. That serializes fine, and I can unpack it on the other side. I would much rather have the proper typing, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service Proxy does not handle the Actor references like Actor Proxy does. Services stack is independent of the actor and does not have knowledge of the actor references. Instead of passing the actor interface, you can pass the actor reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.get.aspx) and then bind (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.actorreference.bind.aspx) the actor reference to the actor interface type on the receiving side. You can cast the output of the binding method to the actor interface.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had figured this out in my head after a couple hours of thinking "how could this be built?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a simple DataContract-decorated POCO and not an interface. DataContractSerializer won't work on an interface. The same rules that would apply for WCF also apply to Service Fabric.

Comment: I am able to pass interfaces with `ActorProxy` however, as mentioned. For instance: `var p = ActorProxy.Create<IRemoteActor>(id); await p.Invoke(this);`